# Recycler view in Horizontal Scroll bar shows only two items

Tags: java, android

I am building a social media app, and I wanted to add story scroll view. The problem I am facing is my recycler view is showing only two items however I gave it 4 or more.

I am using horizontal scroll view because I have a first item that says "click to add story" which is different than those items in recycler view. I am new in android building so any help would be appreciated,  and I checked different solutions but none were helpful. The only success I got was to increase layout-width of recycler view to 1000dp that helps in scrolling but that's not efficient. My home fragment code, where problem is occurred:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_story_scroll_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"


    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/click_add_story_img_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/rain_drops_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:riv_border_color="#333333"
                app:riv_border_width="2dip"
                app:riv_corner_radius="20dip"
                app:riv_mutate_background="true"
                app:riv_tile_mode="repeat" />


            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_story_img_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/black_shade"
                app:background="@color/light_red"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/click_add_story_img_id"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/click_add_story_img_id"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:riv_border_color="#333333"
                app:riv_border_width="2dip"
                app:riv_corner_radius="20dip"
                app:riv_mutate_background="true"
                app:riv_tile_mode="repeat" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_story"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add_3_icon"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/click_add_story_img_id" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/baloo_bhai"
                android:text="Click to add Story"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/click_add_story_img_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_story" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/story_rv_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

My Adapter:

```
package com.assadcoorp.socialstar.Package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.assadcoorp.socialstar.DataTypes.StoryDataType;
import com.assadcoorp.socialstar.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoryAdapter.viewHolder>{
    ArrayList<StoryDataType> list;
    Context context;

    public StoryAdapter(ArrayList<StoryDataType> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_story,parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        StoryDataType model=list.get(position);
        holder.story_image.setImageResource(model.getStory());
        holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(model.getProfile());
        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.live_status.setImageResource(model.getStatus());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView story_image,profile_pic,live_status;
        TextView name;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            story_image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_story_img_id);
            profile_pic=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_pic_img_id);
            live_status=itemView.findViewById(R.id.live_status_id);
            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_txt_id);
        }
    }
}
```

My database:

```
package com.assadcoorp.socialstar.DataTypes;

public class StoryDataType {
    int status;
    String name;
    int story,profile;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getStory() {
        return story;
    }

    public void setStory(int story) {
        this.story = story;
    }

    public int getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(int profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    public StoryDataType(int status, String name, int story, int profile) {
        this.status = status;
        this.name = name;
        this.story = story;
        this.profile = profile;
    }
}
```

and home fragment:

```
package com.assadcoorp.socialstar;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.assadcoorp.socialstar.DataTypes.StoryDataType;
import com.assadcoorp.socialstar.Package.StoryAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView story_rv;
    ArrayList<StoryDataType> story_list;
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        story_rv=view.findViewById(R.id.story_rv_id);
        story_list = new ArrayList<>();
        story_list.add(new StoryDataType(R.drawable.live,"Dragon",R.drawable.rain_drops_bg,R.drawable.profile_icon));
        story_list.add(new StoryDataType(R.drawable.live,"Dragon",R.drawable.rain_drops_bg,R.drawable.profile_icon));
        story_list.add(new StoryDataType(R.drawable.live,"Dragon",R.drawable.rain_drops_bg,R.drawable.profile_icon));
        story_list.add(new StoryDataType(R.drawable.live,"Dragon",R.drawable.rain_drops_bg,R.drawable.profile_icon));
        StoryAdapter adapter=new StoryAdapter(story_list,getContext());
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        story_rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        //story_rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        story_rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        return  view;
    }
}
```

and sample recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_story_img_id"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/rain_drops_bg"
        app:background="@color/light_red"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:riv_border_color="#333333"
        app:riv_corner_radius="20dip"
        app:riv_mutate_background="true"
        app:riv_tile_mode="repeat" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_pic_img_id"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/user_story_img_id"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/user_story_img_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/user_story_img_id" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_pic_ring_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/user_profile_pic_img_id"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/user_profile_pic_img_id"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_profile_pic_img_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/user_profile_pic_img_id"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/live_status_id"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_story_img_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/user_story_img_id"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/live" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name_txt_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/light_black_shade"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/user_story_img_id"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_story_img_id" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why use Horizontal scroll view outside of Recycler view

Comment: @Vikas because I got one different item to be added with recycler view.

Answer (score -1):

try to initialize your Arraylist in the HomeFragment class like this   ArrayList story_list=new ArrayList();
and if you are using firebase to get the data create a empty constructor in the StoryDataType class;